# apache 2.4 won't serve from /tmp

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Under Apache 2.2, I routinely developed web apps from /tmp/checkouts. Installing a vanilla Ubuntu 18.10 gave `me apache 2.4.34-1ubuntu2`. I'm using 2.4 Require directives:

```
    Alias /tmp/checkouts /tmp/checkouts
    <Directory /tmp/checkouts>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        DirectoryIndex Overview index
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

but always get "The requested URL /tmp/checkouts/ was not found on this server.". The same directives work in /home/eric/checkouts. I was able to mv checkouts and serve from /home/checkouts, /checkouts, and /t2/checkouts, where /t2 has the same permissions as /tmp.

I'm currently serving from /t2 and symlinked /tmp/checkouts to /t2/checkouts (so I don't have to re-program my fingers). I tried swapping so that /t2/checkouts symlinked to /tmp/checkouts, adding `<Directory>` blocks for both, with the /t2/checkouts block including `Options FollowSymLinks`, but got this in my error.log (with LogLevel debug): `Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /t2/checkouts`.

Is (the Ubuntu release of) apache2.4 specifically forbidden from serving from /tmp? I don't see "tmp" in any file under `/etc/apache2` except my `sites-enabled` conf (and `sites-available` symlink to it). I also made sure there were no emacs droppings (`~` files) in any conf directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The systemd unit `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` is configured with `PrivateTmp=true`, a [security feature](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/security.html) that tells `systemd` to mount an isolated directory like `/tmp/systemd-private-59bcc3ad6775562f845953cf01624225-apache2.service-3Rtcsk/tmp` over `/tmp` in the filesystem namespace for the `apache2` process and its children.

Compare `sudo ls /proc/$(cat /run/apache2/apache2.pid)/root/tmp` with `sudo ls /tmp`.

I’d recommend just picking a different location.  Somewhere in `/srv` would be typical.

Comment: Huh, I wonder if there's some way for Apache to notice that and warn folks. Is Apache using /tmp or is it just disabling it to protect someone else on the same machine from injecting some evil javascript? (Folks wanting to disable this, e.g if all users are trusted, can edit and run `systemctl daemon-reload`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Messing around with a lot of configuration files of apache, never thought that the problem is related to systemd.